# information retrieval compare wordds

Tags: algorithm, information-retrieval

I have about 3 million words coming from many paper researches.

I want to filter that researches according to meta data.

the research is about cars, books, foods.

for example, I have a document with meta data `Toyota`

I have another document with meta data `Toiota`

notice that `Toiota` is the same as `Toyota`

what are the available approaches to solve that problem please?

#### What I have tried

I used a stem to take the root of the word.

1. I stem the first word to take the root
2. I stem the second word to take the root
3. compare the two roots.

#### My problem

The stem works just on words that have meaning. for example, `eating, eat, ate`. but when the word doesn't have meaning like `Toyota`, the root of it is the exact same word.

#### Another problem

The stem also doesn't work in this case:

united state doesn't equal US but logically they are the same.

anyone has a better approach too?

I don't know what are the available tags in StackOverFlow that works with me problem so you are welcome to add tags.

#### Update 1

I want to search this problem in gooogle but I don't know the correct words to use when searching, could you help me pelase?

Comment: You could do some distance matching, but brand names are going to be near impossible to solve (e.g. Lyft should not be the same as Lift).

Comment: @VonLion no solution for brand names at all?

Comment: @VonLion I have updated my question, could you check pleaes?

Comment: I'm at a loss (not an AI expert by any stretch), but maybe someone else will chip in :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want Toiota to mean the same as Toyota, there are a few options:

1. Hard code the translation
2. Auto "spell check" the query/document. If Toiota does not exist in your dictionary, then return the closest word, if it's close. See Norvig's spelling corrector.
3. Compare documents on character similarity and not exact word matches {t,o,y,o,t,a} has 83% overlap with {t,o,i,o,t,a} . Check out Jaro-Winkler distance too.

For US/United States you probably want a synonym file (of countries and their abbreviations), and add synonyms for each document. Another approach would be to take words and auto-abbreviate them and add that in your index. Example

```
abbrev('United States') = {'united,'states','us'} --take first letter of each word in multi-part words

abbrev('Canada') = {'canada', 'can'} -- take first three letters of single letter words
```